# Why my therminal dont show a box to i write on them if i import and use the "Scanner" like this on java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

```
package leitura;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nome = in.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that the terminal will be shown at the bottom of the Window.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I think you should change your class name from 'main' to any other valid identifier. and you'd better add some words to prompt you to enter in. such as System.out.print("Please enter name:");